# concatenate all argv values to one string using snprintf in C

Tags: c, concatenation, command-line-arguments, printf

How can I concatenate all the values in argv to one string using snprintf?

if i pass in values like `./prog val1 val2 val3 val4`

my string 
 `char all_values[MAX_LEN]` should be "`val1 val2 val3 val4`"

How can I do this efficiently using `snprintf()`?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? I only ask because it will affect how precise an answer I give.

Comment: No it is not a homework problem. I had not been working in C for some time now and I am unable to figure this out correctly.

Comment: Why are you interested in using snprintf()?  As opposed to, e.g., strcat()?

Comment: If your goal is to pass them to another program with `system` or something, this is a **very bad** approach. Instead use `execv` or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 16
int main(int ac, char **av) {
   char buffer[MAX_LEN];
   buffer[0] = 0;
   int offset = 0;
   while(av++,--ac) {
      int toWrite = MAX_LEN-offset;
      int written = snprintf(buffer+offset, toWrite, "%s ", *av);
      if(toWrite < written) {
          break;
      }
      offset += written;
   }
   printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Comment: No need for the `buffer[MAX_LEN-1] = 0;` as "output bytes beyond the n-1st shall be discarded instead of being written to the array, and a null byte is written at the end of the bytes actually written into the array" (POSIX, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was working from the Linux man page, and couldn't find that assurance. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you to want make a print of N arguments, you can do

```
int i = 1 ; // first parameter is a program name  
while(i < argc )
{
   printf("%s",argv[1]);
   i++;
}
```

But if you want to use a string in other processor,you would really concatenate then. Maybe with:

```
char* string_result; 

int  i = 1; 

int  size_total = 0;
bool space_needed = false;

while(i < argc) { // argc contain the number of arguments
   size_total += strlen(argv[i])+1; //+1 for a new space each time.
   i++;
}

if(i > 2) {
    space_needed = true;
    size_total -= 1; //no need for space at end of string
}

string_result = (char*)malloc((size_total+1)*sizeof(char));

string_result[0] = 0 ; // redundant?

i = 1;

while(i < argc) {
   strcat(string_result,argv[i]); // caution to concatenate argv string, memory of OS. 
   if(space_needed && (i+1) < argc)
        strcat(string_result, " "); //space so it looks better.
   i++;
}

//free pointer when done using it.
free(string_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sizoeof(char)==1, untested code!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    int  i ; 
    int  size_total = 0;
    size_t *lens=(size_t *)malloc((argc)*sizeof(size_t));
    for (i=1;i < argc; i++) {
        lens[i]=strlen(argv[i]);
        size_total += lens[i]+1;
    }
    concatinated = (char*)malloc(size_total);
    char *start=concatinated;
    for (i=1;i < argc; i++) {
        memcpy(start, argv[i], lens[i]);
        start+=lens[i];
        *start=' ';
        start++;
    }
    start--;
    *start=0;
    free(lens);
```